# Cannot get the value from list key C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to get the value from an list by their key. I send the list from one form to another. This is windows form application See my code:

```
    /* First form! */     
    var list1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
    list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Cat", 1));
    form2 f3 = new form2(connection , list1);


    /* Form2 */
    private IList<KeyValuePair<string, int>> _theList;

    public editAccount(string connection, List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> arr)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _theList = arr;

        label1.Text = _theList["Cat"];

    }
```

I think it is obviously what I try to do, so any help is great!

SOLVED : Thanks tons to stackoverflow user `Sriram Sakthivel`! Solution:

```
    /* First form*/
    Dictionary<string, string> openWith = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
    openWith.Add("cat", "test");
    editAccount f3 = new editAccount(connection, openWith);

    /* Form 2 */
    private Dictionary<string, string> _theList;

    public editAccount(string connection, Dictionary<string, string> arr)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _theList = arr;


        label1.Text = _theList["cat"];

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to access values via `key` then you should use keyed collection such as [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). List can be accessed only via index, it doesn't define a indexer which takes string as parameter.

Apart from that, keys are case sensitive by default. If you need a insensitive key you can [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988643/case-insensitive-dictionary-with-string-key-type-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Dictionary is something different to List then? So I should replace em?

Comment: @TorrBallen Dictionary is based on [HashTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) which provides efficient access to elements via key. If you need to access via key then `Dictionary` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks again, `Dictionary` worked just fine. Updated main post with final code.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about case you may use [String.ToLower](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78f86at(v=vs.110).aspx) or [String.ToUpper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper(v=vs.110).aspx) methods while setting or using your keys.

Also you should use [`Dictionary<String, Int32>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to access your values by [string index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyxt2e2h(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var list1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Cat".ToUpper(), 1));
form2 f3 = new form2(connection , list1);


/* Form2 */
private IDictionary<string, Int32> _theList;

public editAccount(string connection,IDictionary<string, Int32> arr)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _theList = arr;

    label1.Text = _theList["cat".ToUpper()].ToString();
}
```

Comment: `IList<T>` doesn't have indexer with string as parameter.

Comment: Actually, Microsoft recommends you use ToUpper(), not ToLower(), when working with case-insensitive things like keys or comparison. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look things up by key you don't want a
     `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` you want a
    `Dictionary<string, int>`.  So replace all occurrances of `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` and, as already stated, your key is case sensitive.

for Lists the [n] indexer wants an int and is used to get the n-th item in the List

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary for this, it is optimised for this by hashing the keys for much quicker retrieval.

That said, if you want a list, one option is to perform a linq query on it.

```
_list.Where(p => p.Key == "cat");
```