# how to add stringcomparer to nested dictionary in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

how to assign this read only variable in constructor.

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> nCount = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

Want to initialize this variable in constructor:

```
  public mclass() {

        nCount = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();

    }
```

on the initializing time need to add a stringComparer to inner Dictornary

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988643/case-insensitive-dictionary-with-string-key-type-in-c-sharp??

Comment: You can't initialize the inner dictionary without an item in the main dictionary. So when you add the items you initialize the value's dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize every dictionary within the outer one calling the constructor-overload for `IEqualityComparer`.

```
nCount = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> 
{
    { "myKey", new Dictionary<string, int>(..., myEqualityComparer) }    
};
```

However mostly you won´t need to fully initialize the dictionary within the constructor. It might be sufficient to simply declare it and add its members later.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize the inner dictionary without an item in the main dictionary. So when you add the items you initialize the dictionary by passing  the `StringComparer` to the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132073(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

```
public mclass()
{
    nCount = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
    var innerDict1 = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    innerDict1.Add("Foo", 1);
    nCount.Add("Bah", innerDict1);
}
```